# Feh in startup script only displaying images on reboot, not startup?

Tags: python, boot, display

I have a Python script running on a Raspberry Pi Zero W that calls the image program feh in order to loop through some directories and display the enclosed images. The script is supposed to run on startup - think of it as a sort of headless image-display program. I'm running not the *latest* version of Stretch, but the one released in Oct. 2018.

In order to get everything to run on startup, I've edited the `~/.config/lxsessions/LXDE-pi/autostart` file. I'm using an external projector, so in order to display the images correctly, my autostart file looks like this:

```
DISPLAY=:0
/usr/bin/python /home/pi/myscript.py
```

Then my Python script basically looks like

```
import os
import psutil
import time
while True:
    os.system('feh --hide-pointer -x -q -B black -g 1280x720 ' + img_dir + ' &')
    time.sleep(4)
    for process in psutil.process_iter():
        if 'feh' in process.cmdline():
            process.terminate()
```

and I loop through different image directories. I know that using `os` to make system calls is deprecated, but it's the only way I could get this particular call to work.

So here's the problem: if I reboot the Pi from the command line, everything works swimmingly. The Pi boots up, the Python starts running, and the images are displayed correctly, looping forever. If I do a cold start, however, only the Python script runs - no images are displayed. I know this is happening because I can log in remotely and see that the Python program is indeed running, but feh is not, while it is running after a reboot.

The only other thing I can think might be relevant is that I had issues with the Pi's projector/display going to sleep (i.e., going dark after no external input after a minute or so), so I edited the `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` file and added

```
xserver-command=X -s 0 -dpms
```

What's going on with feh? Is there a log file somewhere I can look at to see if it's throwing any errors? Is my no-sleep call screwing things up? Why does the Python run without fail, but not feh? Any input here is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that comes across this, the answer is to sleep for a while. In the autostart file, adding the line

```
sleep 5
```

between

```
DISPLAY=:0
```

and

```
/usr/bin/python /home/pi/myscript.py
```

apparently allows all necessary display drivers to load before feh and the Python script start. Problem solved, as long as you don't mind waiting a few extra seconds.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. This will finish the question and it will not pop up every year again.